# how to test for a presence of a text in a view page?

Tags: grails, integration-testing

When doing integration tests, does Grails have any methods that assert the presence of a text in the view page?

For example: sometimes we want to assert that the view page contains certain elements. For example: in a movies list page we want to assert the given movies are shown in the view page. How can we achieve that effectively in Grails? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well! As per my knowledge when we render a view we get String in return and hence you could use String's contains method to test whether page contains some text or not.

There are plenty of such examples available.

Below is the one from http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2013/05/grails-goodness-testing-views-and.html blog:

```
package com.grails.views

import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.web.GroovyPageUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestMixin(GroovyPageUnitTestMixin)
class HeaderTemplateSpecification extends Specification {

    def "if username is set then show message Hi with username"() {
        expect: 'Template output must contain Hi, Johnson'
       (render(template: '/sample/header', model: [username: 'Johnson'])).contains 'Hi, Johnson'
    }

}
```

Above, if you notice have rendered gsp view and checked for presence of  `Hi,mrhaki` string in view.

Hope it answers your question.